# what is "missing keyword" in SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

I've been searched that statement. but I don't solcved my problem. so I ask you something. please somebody help me

below statement is my query, and error statement

```
create table rp_board(
    rpbno number primary key,           -- pk
    m_id varchar2(100) not null,        -- fk
    rp_list varchar2(100) not null,
    rp_title varchar2(100) not null,
    rp_content varchar2(2000) not null,
    rp_time date default sysdate,
    rp_update date default sysdate,
    
    constraint fk_rp_board foreign key(m_id) reference member(m_id)
);
```

**ORA-00905: missing keyword
00905. 00000 -  "missing keyword"**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not a (key)**word** that's missing, but a **letter**. It is `references`, not `reference`.

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE rp_board
  2  (
  3     rpbno        NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,                                      -- pk
  4     m_id         VARCHAR2 (100) NOT NULL,                                 -- fk
  5     rp_list      VARCHAR2 (100) NOT NULL,
  6     rp_title     VARCHAR2 (100) NOT NULL,
  7     rp_content   VARCHAR2 (2000) NOT NULL,
  8     rp_time      DATE DEFAULT SYSDATE,
  9     rp_update    DATE DEFAULT SYSDATE,
 10     CONSTRAINT fk_rp_board FOREIGN KEY (m_id) REFERENCES MEMBER (m_id)
 11  );

Table created.

SQL>
```

Comment: Thank you! you are amazing!!